# What does the @ symbol do in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue.js and I am looking at someone's code. I noticed they are using the @ symbol. What does this do and what is it used for?

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    handleCreate() {
      console.log('Child has been created.');
    }
  }
};

<template>
  <ChildComponent @created="handleCreate" />
</template>

// ChildComponent
export default {
  created() {
    this.$emit('created');
  }
}
```

Comment: It's shorthand for `v-on`

Comment: Is that also for the colons (:)

Comment: As Matt said, have a look here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-on-Shorthand

Comment: @Whymess colons are shorthand for `v-bind`

Answer (score 22):

In your case, the @ symbol, symbol is shorthand for [`v-on`](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-on).
It can also be used when importing to resolve things.